# How to Display a Flash Message Immediately from Within a Controller Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**flash.now[:class]** is supposed to work differently from, e.g. **flash.keep[:class]** but doesn't seem to for me.  I've got **flash.keep** messages working all over my jRuby/Rails app but now I want to display a message immediately to assure the user that I'm working to fulfill the request *BEFORE* my controller method redirects.  Why doesn't **flash.now** work this way?  I've already followed it with a **render** instruction but that's not allowed if you also have a **redirect_to** elsewhere in your controller method, which I need in order to return to the main view.  If not **flash.now** then what should I use, or is what I'm trying to do just not possible in Rails?

The controller code isn't much more than what's shown above:

```
 flash.now[:info] = '* * * Working hard to fulfill your request... * * *'
 render :action => 'index'
```

I added the **render** instruction in an attempt to make **flash.now** flash ***now*** but the preprocessor didn't like my having both a **render** and a **redirect_to** in the same method.  I need the **redirect_to** further down as part of the normal and typical design of my RESTful application.

But the main point is that **flash.now** does *not* flash now.  So how is it different from, e.g. **flash.keep** or just **flash**?

Comment: Why is this question tagged Adobe Flash?

Comment: @downvoter Why was this down voted? May not be the most formatted question but don't see the need for a down vote. I gave it a +1

Comment: Can you post some controller code? I'm a little confused on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: +1 Azolo. Need to see some controller code before we can know what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Post updated with controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `flash.now`.  You mention that you `redirect_to` within that action, and `flash.now` only shows up when you `render` (the difference being that `redirect_to` results in a whole 'nother HTTP request, and thus another action; `flash.now` is [only visible in the current action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now)).

So if you want that message to show up when your processing is done, just use the flash normally.

If you want to do it in two stages, though (a confirmation message when you get the HTTP request, and then a redirect when it finishes processing), it's trickier.  You can't create two HTTP responses for a single HTTP request, so you're going to have to fake it with JavaScript.

I'm guessing that since your action takes long enough to process that it needs a "Still Working..." message, it's a result of a form submission.  So make a form submit event handler that displays your message (and/or replaces the submit button with a "working" icon - this keeps impatient users from plugging up your server (and possibly breaking their data) by compulsively submitting again and again).  That lets your users know that you did in fact get their request, and are working on it*.  Then, when your action completes, just redirect or render as you normally would.

Hope that helps!

*Since it's just a JavaScript function, it doesn't *know* that the server actually got the response, but this is one of those cases where UX trumps technical pedantry.

Comment: Ok thanks, Xavier, I'll look into form submit event handlers.  And yes, it is case #2 in that my action '...takes long enough to process that it needs a "Still Working..." message'.  I tried chaining my controller methods to accomplish this but it became too convoluted.  A flash message won't show up until the original page is redisplayed, so the special event handler will have to use a different display technique which won't be consistent with the flash messages.

Comment: By the way, how _is_ **flash.now** different from **flash.keep**?

Comment: @Dave - `flash.now` adds something to the flash for the current action _only_.  The normal flash setters `flash[:notice]=` and `flash.notice=` add their data to the flash for the current action _and_ the next action.  `flash.keep` keeps flash data around for an additional action when it would otherwise expire.  Essentially, `flash.now` is for `render`, `flash.notice=` is for `redirect_to`, and `flash.keep` lets you keep your data around for an extra action.

Comment: And a [more detailed writeup](http://travisonrails.com/2008/08/17/working-with-the-flash-hash) - might be more useful than I was.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, Xavier!  I'm going to change all of my flash.keep messages to flash.notice to prevent overlaps in the feedback on successive actions.

Comment: Update: Using jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_26) [linux-i386-java] with Rails 3.2.0.rc2 and JDBC SQLite 3.7.2, **flash.now** displays nothing, **flash.notice** generates a **NoMethodError** exception and **flash.keep** displays my message but hangs around for a second action.  I must have been here before, which is why I ended up settling for **flash.keep**.

Comment: Update: Just plain **flash** with no method specification using jruby 1.6.5 with Rails 3.2.0.rc2 achieves the aforestated effect of **flash.notice**.

Comment: Update: As I continue to use my app, it's become apparent that just plain **flash** with no method specification using jruby 1.6.5 with Rails 3.2.0.rc2 achieves the same effect as **flash.keep**.  - Deja vu, I've been here before...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can redirect_to OR render only once in each action.

Why don't you just use this instead

```
render :action => 'index', :notice => '* * * Working hard to fulfill your request... * * *'
```

or

```
flash[:notice] = '* * * Working hard to fulfill your request... * * *'
render :action => 'index'
```